# How to read multiple text input from user

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am creating an app for calculating centroid ,orthocenter, etc.
So I needed to take input from the user but I'm having trouble in reading the data entered by them.

I get an error,
Error says : `screenmanager has no attribute text`

Code:

```py
    from kivy.lang import Builder 
    from kivymd.app import MDApp 
    from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
    from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel 
    from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
    from kivymd.uix.button import  MDRoundFlatButton

    # Builder 
    helper_string = """ 
    ScreenManager: 
       Entry: 

    <Entry>: 
         name:"input" 
         MDLabel: 
             text:"X1" 
             halign:"left" 
             pos_hint:{'center_y': 0.95} 

         MDTextField: 
             id: x1
             hint_text:"Enter X1" 
             helper_text: "abscissa"
             helper_text_mode:"on_focus" 
             pos_hint:{'center_x':0.17, 'center_y':0.95} 
             size_hint:(0.1,0.1) 
             width:5

          MDLabel: 
              text:"Y1" 
              halign:"center" 
              pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.40, 'center_y': 0.95}
              

          MDTextField: 
              id: y1
              hint_text:"Enter Y1" 
              helper_text: "ordinate"
              helper_text_mode:"on_focus" 
              pos_hint:{'center_x':0.55, 'center_y':0.95}
              size_hint:(0.1,0.1) 
              width:5 

          MDLabel: 
              text:"X2" 
              halign:"left" 
              pos_hint:{'center_y': 0.85} 

          MDTextField: 
              id: x2
              hint_text:"Enter X2" 
              helper_text: "abscissa"
              helper_text_mode:"on_focus" 
              pos_hint:{'center_x':0.17, 'center_y':0.85}
              size_hint:(0.1,0.1) 
              width:5 

         MDLabel: 
             text:"Y2" 
             halign:"center" 
             pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.40, 'center_y': 0.85} 
             

         MDTextField: 
             id: y2
             hint_text:"Enter Y2"
             helper_text: "ordinate"    
             helper_text_mode:"on_focus" 
             pos_hint:{'center_x':0.55, 'center_y':0.85} 
             size_hint:(0.1,0.1) 
             width:5 

         MDLabel: 
             text:"X3" 
             halign:"left" 
             pos_hint:{'center_y': 0.75} 

         MDTextField:
             id: x3 
             hint_text:"Enter X3" 
             helper_text: "abscissa"
             helper_text_mode:"on_focus" 
             pos_hint:{'center_x':0.17, 'center_y':0.75}
             size_hint:(0.1,0.1) 
             width:5 

         MDLabel: 
             text:"Y3" 
             halign:"center" 
             pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.40, 'center_y': 0.75} 
             

         MDTextField: 
             id: y3
             hint_text:"Enter Y3" 
             helper_text: "ordinate"
             helper_text_mode:"on_focus" 
             pos_hint:{'center_x':0.55, 'center_y':0.75}
             size_hint:(0.1,0.1) 
             width:5
    """
    class Entry(Screen): 
        pass

    sm = ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(Entry(name='input')) 


    class TriangleApp(MDApp): 
        def build(self): 
             screen = Screen()   
             self.theme_cls.primary_palette =  "Green" 
             button =  MDRoundFlatButton(text="Submit",   
             pos_hint={'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.60}, on_release=self.show)
             self.help_str = Builder.load_string(helper_string)
             screen.add_widget(self.help_str)
             screen.add_widget(button) 
             return screen 

        def show(self, obj):
            entr = sm.get_screen('input') 
            xx1 = entr.ids['x1'].txt
            yy1 = entr.ids['y1'].txt
            xx2 = entr.ids['x2'].txt
            yy2 = entr.ids['y2'].txt
            xx3 = entr.ids['x3'].txt
            yy3 = entr.ids['y3'].txt
            print(xx1, yy1, xx2, yy2, xx3, yy3)

    TriangleApp().run()
```

I tired printing the values in console using show(self, obj) function but it didn't work.

**I added id to each MDTextField and tried calling them in show() but it showed a TypeError**

I want all the 6 coordinates to be submitted at once on clicking submit button.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to format your code properly (with proper indentation) for easy access.

Comment: You need to bind some callback in order to access whatever text you type in the `TextInput`s.

Comment: @ApuCoder Can you please help me how to do that and where to add those statements. I'll be grateful to you.

Comment: Try formatting your code using proper indentation.

Comment: @ApuCoder tried, but the result was same

Answer (score 0):

So here is a little code you can input how many inputs you want then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and it will store all the data at random. Like to be precise it will make a list name random or whatever you wanna call it.

```
   import sys
   random = sys.stdin.readlines()
   print(random)
```

Or you can refer to this site https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python/ it is another way to take inputs.

Comment: It threw an error saying TypeError :  "  'ScreenManager object cannot be interpreted as an  integer "

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).